# How to save masked image to camera roll or to share social media

Tags: ios, objective-c, mask

I can mask an image perfectly after mask is done perfectly when I am trying to save the masked image, it is saving as normal image without mask.or can some post the code to save with mask Please help me. Here's the code -

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

CGImageRef imager = [image CGImage];
CGImageRef maskRef = [maskImage CGImage];
CGImageRef actualMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imager, actualMask);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
  - (IBAction)mask:(id)sender
{
imageView.image = [self maskImage:imageView.image withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask"]];
   }

- (IBAction)shareorsave:(id)sender {

NSArray *itemsToShare =@[imageView.image];


UIActivityViewController *activityVC =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];


[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
@end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that's actually saving the image?

Comment: in IBAction share and save,, using this code normally we can save or share but unable to save as masked ,,

Comment: That just presents the activityViewController. Can you show the code that's called when the user selects that they wish to save the image?

Comment: in IOS7  with UIActivityViewController we can save and share whatever active on ios its pops up in Control Center

Comment: What happens when the user picks one of the options in UIActivityViewController

Comment: You should be able to save the image using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(maskedImage, nil, nil, nil);`. I'm asking about how _you_ are saving the image, to help answer your question.

Comment: oh sorry its not working if we use the picks one for UIActivityViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you still got the thing figured it out but I faced the same problem. Try to render the `imageView`'s layer as folllows :

```
 if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

   [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

   UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then add in `itemsToShare` the `newImage`.

Don't forget to add `QuartzCore.framework` and

```
#import  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: yeah i imported this #import  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>  already..where i need to add this code

Comment: Before declaring the itemsToShare array, in the shareorsave function.

Comment: its not taking the newImage in items to share ,,  if u can help me i can send u my file please give me your email id

Comment: I can't post it here in a public way, I don't know how to give you a private message either. Could you give me more details about the error? What do you mean by the newImage it's not taken in itemsToShareArray?

Comment: yea its working now :D after getting idea from your code i made few changes ,thanks a lot again